# Any way to fix PDF fonts when viewing in Firefox on Linux?

Tags: firefox, pdf-reader

It's really nice to be able to view a PDF in Firefox on Linux but the font is absolutely horrid and the kerning is way off:

[image]

The PDF is super easy to read in Chrome:

[image]

Is there a way to make the PDF font in Firefox more readable?

Comment: Which distro are you on? Do you have [these fonts](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/urw-base35-fonts) installed on your system?

Comment: Thank you! MUCH better now!

Answer (score 2):

The below setting helped me:

Just `uncheck` the **Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above** in *Firefox --> Settings/Preferences --> Fonts --> Advanced*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This solved my problem. Though I'm wondering which other websites now will have problems if their fonts aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug related to this (or a similar) issue in the Firefox snap on Ubuntu. A fix has been committed a few days ago; more info and a workaround can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1971608

Workaround suggested there:

```
$ mkdir ~/snap/firefox/current/.config/fontconfig/conf.d
$ cp /etc/fonts/conf.d/* ~/snap/firefox/current/.config/fontconfig/conf.d
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on Arch Linux with firefox. Based on the comment from @Tom Yan, I found this [`gsfonts`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/gsfonts/) package, which after installing and reloading the PDF in firefox, made things look much better.